Bounding list chromatic number of a bipartite graph
Let $G$ be a bipartite graph on $n$ vertices, show that $\chi_l(G) \leq 1 + \log_2(n)$.
So far I have:
Let
$k=1 + \log_2(n)$ and $L_1, \dots, L_n$ be $k-$element lists for the vertices of $G$. Randomly color the vertices of $G$ and denote $X_i$ the indicator random variable that $v_i$ is not properly colored.
Define $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, we want to show that $P(X=0)>0$. To this end we compute the expected values of the $X_i$. This is where I get stuck,
$P(X_i=1)= 1-P(v_i \text{ is properly colored}) = 1- \frac{\#\text{proper colors available}}{k} \geq 1-\frac{k-|N(v_i)|}{k}$.
And this fraction could, a priori, be negative. Anything that I am missing?
